# EntityManager null when trying to migrate to JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, migration, jboss7.x, entitymanager

I am currently trying to migrate my web application from JBoss 5.1 to JBoss 7.1.1. I inject the entity manager into my jsp file but the entity manager is always null.

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <!-- SSIS2 Productive Database --> 
    <persistence-unit name="SSIS2" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/SSIS2DSprod</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Example of Entity Manager injection in a JSP file:

```
<%! @PersistenceContext(unitName = "SSIS2")
    public EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;
%>
```

The deployment itself contains no errors, so what is the problem with the Entity Manager here? It works without problems on JBoss 5.1.

Edit:
datasource in standalone.xml: (ip-address and SSID removed)

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/SSIS2DSprod" pool-name="SSIS2DSprod" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip-address:1531:SSID</connection-url>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>ssis2</user-name>
                        <password>ssis2</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't set datasource in JBoss?

Comment: It is set. Also the security domain is set. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Hmm... I don't know how in JBoss 5 or 7, but in JBoss 6 datasource defining file name has to end with "-ds.xml". Try changing the filename.

Comment: No, it completely changed in JBoss 7 and is now located in standalone.xml or in domain.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that ressource injection into JSP is not permitted anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your persistence.xml is under META-INF folder.